A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'. compileSdkVersion is not specified
Estoy desarrollando un app movil en react native expo y me sale este error:
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
En el grandle tengo esto:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
   ext {
       buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0'
       minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
       compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33')
       targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33')
       kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.8.10'
       frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

       // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
       ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
   }
   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
       classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven {
           // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
           url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
       }
       maven {
           // Android JSC is installed from npm
           url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
       }

       google()
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
   }
}


Estuve probando cambiando versiones o añadiendo plugins y sigue igual
